# I am doing so much checking in my handlers to insure that server doesn't hang , but is it the best practice?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, prisma

I am working on a simple app and i am implementing the authentication functions but i always do checks after every method i get or post it to the database because i can't trust user's input and i am making sure that the server never hangs, but i feel like it's too much and i don't know if this is the best way to do it  or not but i see that i repeat these checks alot.

here is an example

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSRRG.png)

so is it fine that i always check if the user is there or not or if the token is there or if the password matches or should i do it in Middleware?

Comment: On the createNewUser you could remove the checks for user and token, as the only way user and token to doesnt exists would be a error, witch would cause the try catch to happen. For the signin method just you could remove just the token check, as the others one are necessary as the user may not exists.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Checking for data inside api methods is a part of the development and are necessary to create good error responses.

On `createNewUser` method you could remove the checks for user and token. If a error happens on `prisma.user.create` or `newToken` the try catch would be trigger. You should update the catch to send a message to user, something like a default message for that method(Something bad happen when creating user).

On `signin` method you could remove the check for token for the same reason. The other checks seens good(user and matchedPassword) but you could change the error message to something like "Incorrect user password or email.", saying whats is wrong on login(password or email) isnt good.